# MySQL Prepared Statment of Update in Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

I have to update a multiple table records in multiple databases. When I use the prepared statement and execute that it does not work. but when I execute the statement it works.

```
set @u = concat("Update `",pDB_NAME,"`.`",pTABLE_NAME,"` set 
        `NAME` ='",pNAME,"',
        `FATHER` ='",pFATHER,"',
        `REGNO` ='",pREGNO,"',
        `SEX` ='",pSEX,"',
        `STATUS` ='",pSTATUS,"',
        `DOB` ='",pDOB,"',
        `DISTT` ='",pDISTT,"',
        `NOC_ISSUED` ='",pNOC_ISSUED,"',
        `ADDRESS` ='",pADDRESS,"',
        `CONTACTNO` ='",pCONTACTNO,"',
        `CNIC` ='",pCNIC,"',
        `FCNIC` ='",pFCNIC,"',
        `SPECIALITY` ='",pSPECIALITY,"',
        `NATIONALITY` ='",pNATIONALITY,"',
        `RELIGION` ='",pRELIGION,"',
        `MEDIUM` ='",pMEDIUM,"',
        `DISTT_CODE` ='",pDISTT_CODE,"',
        `TEH_CODE` ='",pTEH_CODE,"'

          WHERE RNO='",pRNO,"';");
           PREPARE stmt3 FROM @u;
```

`The following statement returns perfect query`

```
   select @u;
```

`But there is no result of the following section`

```
        EXECUTE stmt3;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt3;
```

Comment: Here no result means there is no update happened or sql query is not executed or it execute but didn't returned the no. of rows updated ?

Comment: Yes, query is not executed. Its not updating the record.

Answer (score 0):

Do not quote your column values by wrapping variable values in quotation marks in quoted strings.  It's sloppy, it can mask errors, and opens the door to SQL injection.  Use the `QUOTE()` function.

```
    ...
    `NAME` =",QUOTE(pNAME),",
    `FATHER` =",QUOTE(pFATHER),",
    `REGNO` =",QUOTE(pREGNO),",
    ...
```

This construction also correctly handles escaping and `NULL` values properly, which naive quoted concatenation doesn't.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_quote